# Extraction of Coefficients in the Exponential Function of a Series

Tags: algorithms, power-series

**Question:** Let $f(x) \in x\mathbb{C}[[x]]$. What is the (asymptotically) fastest algorithm for calculating the coefficient of $x^n$ in $e^{f(x)}$?

**Naive Solution 1:** Using fast polynomial multiplication (I assume it takes $O(n \log n)$ time to multiply two polynomials of degree $n$), one can solve this problem with complexity of $O(n^2 \log n)$ by writing $[x^n]e^{f}$ as $[x^n]\sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \frac{f^i}{i!}$, and calculate the (truncated) first $n$'th powers of $f$.

**Naive Solution 2:** This solution utilizes the multicativity of the exponential function. One writes $[x^n]e^f$ as $[x^n] \prod_{i=1}^{n} e^{([x^i]f) \cdot x^i} = [x^n] \prod_{i=1}^{n} (\sum_{j=0}^{n/i} \frac{([x^i]f)^j x^{ij}}{j!})$, and then multiplies $n$ polynomials of degree $n$.

Can one do better (asymptotically)?

Although the example $e^f$ has actually occurred in a calculation I am doing, and the exponential function is abundant in combinatorics, a further natural generalization is: Are there some nice non-rational elementary functions, such as $g(x):-\log(1-x)$, for which $[x^n](g \circ f)$ can be computed faster than $O(n^2 \log n)$?

Comment: You might be interested in the work of K. Kedlaya and C. Umans. Fast modular composition in any characteristic. Proceedings of the 49th Annual IEEE Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science (FOCS). pages 146-155. 2008.

Comment: Note that $g=e^f$ implies $g' = gf'$. This gives a recurrence for the coefficients of $g$ that's easy to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with $O(1)$ polynomial multiplications, i.e. $O(n \log n)$ with your assumptions. One uses Newton's method to invert the logarithm of a power series. The logarithm is computed using $O(1)$ polynomial multiplications as

$$\log(f(x)) = \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}.$$

More generally, one can use similar techniques to evaluate the compositions $g(f(x))$ or $f(g(x))$ rapidly, where $g$ is any function satisfying a sufficiently nice differential equation.

The paper Igor Rivin linked to is a good reference, but just to clarify, this classical result goes back to Brent and Kung (1978). In recent years, several papers have been published that push down the $O(1)$ constant. David Harvey obtained a bound of $13/6 + o(1)$ polynomial multiplications for the exponential of a power series (see http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~davidharvey/papers/fast-exp/index.html), but I'm not sure if this is still the record.

It's worth nothing that there is a Naive Solution 0 that requires $O(n^2)$ operations: the coefficients of $g(x) = e^{f(x)}$ satisfy the recursion

$$[x^k] g = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k j ([x^j]f) ([x^{k-j}] g).$$

Indeed, if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, this algorithm only requires $O(mn)$ operations, which is superior to the other methods if $m = o(\log n)$. The classical division algorithm gives a similar $O(mn)$ method for the logarithm of a power series.

Another remark is that your Naive Solution 2 can be modified to get down to $O(n \log^3 n)$ complexity, using a divide and conquer approach.

All these algorithms actually require you to compute the first $n$ coefficients. As far as I know, it is an open problem whether extracting a single coefficient can be done faster (by more than a constant factor). I believe this is an open problem even for reciprocal of power series.

Comment: Is there a good reference for the openness in the last paragraph?  If so, it might resolve https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51302/extracting-coefficients-of-polynomials-given-by-straight-line-programs.

Comment: I don't have a reference at hand. By the way, one can beat O(n log n) for series of special type: see https://fredrikj.net/blog/2022/01/a-series-complexity-problem/

Comment: Yep, I’m aware of the holonomic case, but as far as I can tell the recurrences grow too quickly to resolve general SLPs.

Answer (score 2):

This question (and many related ones) is answered in [this paper of Bostan, Salvy, and Schost.](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~pborwein/MITACS/papers/BosSalSho.pdf)